# Convert loaded string to Object

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3, I want lo load a file text with URLLoader. In the file text I have the following string:

```
{a:1,b:"string",c:["one","two"]}
```

Is it possible (once loaded) to convert it to an Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to eval the string to create the object.
This is done natively in javascript and AS2. AS3 however does not support this function.
But all is not lost. The people at [Hurlant](http://eval.hurlant.com/) have created a library that does this "almost" as good as native JavaScript.
Here is a good [example](http://danielmclaren.com/node/113).
[And another library example using d.eval](http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/docs/apidoc/r1/deval/D.html#eval%28%29)


I would like to point out though that if you have accept to the source of the object string that you create a JSON object out of it. The JSON libraries are usually much easier and more reliable to use then the libraries that do Eval.

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic deserializer built into the language, no.  But if your text file sticks to the JSON standard, then you could use a JSON parser to do the conversion for you: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fadobe%2Fserialization%2Fjson

Or, if you cannot adhere to JSON, you could always write your own deserializer.

Comment: And just to state the perhaps-obvious, the example in the question is not valid JSON; because file names in JSON must be quoted strings.

Comment: Oh, I never said it was JSON: it's an object of class Object.

Comment: Definitely agree there, what you have is not JSON.  I was merely trying to suggest that it would probably be easier to convert your text to JSON than to write your own deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a sting with JSON format. Use `JSONDecoder` to decode it to an Object, like this:

```
var dc:JSONDecoder = new JSONDecoder("{a:1,b:'string',c:['one','two']}");
var ob:Object = dc.getValue();
```